# Default Initialize or Check For Null

Tags: c++, null, smart-pointers, default-constructor

I'd like to know **is it better to specify a default initialization for a smart-pointer or do a `NULL` value check before accessing the smart-pointers methods?**

Currently I've been using the method below to avoid calling `increment()` on a `NULL` pointer. **Is this a reasonable way of doing things or is there a pitfall that I don't see?**

*Note: We use a custom smart-pointer class and I don't have the Boost libraries on my current configuration to test compile this code. This should compile, but YMMV.*

**Example.h**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() : mFoo(0) {}
  Foo(int rawValue) : mFoo(rawValue) {}

  void  increment() { mFoo++; }

private:
  int mFoo;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooSP;

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass() : mFoo(new Foo()) {}

  FooSP       foo() { return mFoo; }
  void        setFoo(FooSP newFoo) { mFoo = newFoo; }

private:
  FooSP mFoo;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <Example.h>

int main()
{
  MyClass temp;                    // Default-constructed
  temp.foo()->increment();         // Increment Foo's member integer
                                   // Before: mFoo = 0
                                   // After:  mFoo = 1
  FooSP tempFoo = new Foo(10);     // Create a Foo with a default size
  temp.setFoo(FooSP(new Foo(10))); // Explicitly set the FooSP member
  temp.foo()->increment();         // Increment the new FooSP
                                   // Before: mFoo = 10
                                   // After:  mFoo = 11
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two phase initialization is usually something I like to avoid, it doesn't seem like you need a smart pointer at all why not just have a non-pointer member? FWIW, if you have C++11 you can use `nullptr` and `std::shared_ptr` you don't need boost anymore.

Comment: @AJG85 In my actual project the `Foo` object can be quite large and the `mFoo` smart-pointer gets used as an argument to other functions. I was trying to avoid passing by reference; smart-pointers seemed like a simpler way to go. Just FYI I'm on an older linux distribution (not by choice) that does not have C++11.

Comment: @Michael: How is passing smart pointers any simpler than passing references? Automated ref-counting is much simpler than manual ownership management, but still more complicated than nothing at all…

Comment: @Michael A reference is simpler IMO. The advantage is that you don't need to copy the whole object if it's complex and it's guaranteed not to be null. The advantage of a pointer is polymorphism and more control over memory. At least that's my take on it Justin makes some good points below as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it better to specify a default initialization for a smart-pointer or do a NULL value check before accessing the smart-pointers methods?

There is no right answer which applies to every case (more soon). *If* I had to err to one or  the other, I would err toward `NULL` testing without default initialization because that's an obvious programmer error which can be detected and corrected easily.

However, I think the right answer is that there are good reasons we use multiple idioms for construction and initialization, and that you should *choose the best approach for your program*.

Typically, I will be explicit (no default or no default initialization) in the lower level classes, as well as complex higher level classes. When the classes are mid-level and defaults and ownership are more obvious (often because of limited use cases), then a default may be sensible.

Often, you will just want to be consistent, to avoid surprising clients. You'll also need to be aware of the complexity of allocating default-initialized objects. If it's big and complex to create, and a default does not make sense, then you are simply wasting a lot of resources when the default-constructed object is the wrong choice.

- a) do not apply a default where it does not make sense. the default should be obvious.
- b) avoid wasted allocations.

In addition to the approaches you have mentioned, there are a few other angles you might also consider:

- Matching `Foo`'s declared constructors in `MyClass`. At least, the ones which pertain to `MyClass`.
- If copyable and efficient to copy, passing a `Foo` to `MyClass`'s constructor.
- Passing `Foo` in a container (smart pointer in this case) to `MyClass`'s constructor to remove any ambiguity and to offer the client the option to construct (and share, in the case of a shared pointer) `Foo` as they desire.

> Is this a reasonable way of doing things or is there a pitfall that I don't see?

Wasted allocations. Surprising results. It can restrict capabilities. The most obvious, broadly applicable problems are time and resource consumption.

To illustrate some scenarios:

- say Foo reads a 1MB file every time it is constructed. when construction parameters are necessary and the default is not the right option, the file would have to be read a second time. the innocent default would double the disk io required.
- in another case, an omitted construction parameter may be another large or complex shared pointer. if absent, Foo may create its own -- when the resource could/should have been shared.

Constructors parameters are often very important, and often should not be erased from the interface. It's certainly fine to do so in some cases, but these conveniences can introduce a lot of restrictions or introduce much unnecessary allocations and CPU time as the contained object's complexity increases.

Using both approaches in your programs is fine. Using additional approaches I outlined is also fine. Specifically, using *the right approach for the problem* is ideal - there are multiple ways to implement ideal solutions available; you just have to determine what that is in the context of what it is your program is trying to do. All these approaches have separate pros and cons - there is often an ideal match for the context of your program's operation and exposed interfaces.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by *it can restrict capabilities*?

Comment: @Michael expanded in the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a smart pointer as a general replacement for a pointer type, you cannot get away from a check for null. This is because a class defined with a smart pointer with a default constructor is likely to allow the smart pointer to be created with its default constructor. Dynamically creating a new object just to fill the pointer until you can set it seems to be a waste of resources.

`shared_ptr`'s constructor is explicit, so your initialization of `tempFoo` won't compile. If you wanted to save a line of code, you can avoid declaring the temporary like this:

```
temp.setFoo(FooSP(new Foo(10)));
```

You can also declare the method of  `setFoo` to take a constant reference, to avoid manipulating the reference count when taking in the parameter.

```
void setFoo(const FooSP &newFoo) { mFoo = newFoo; }
```

Or use `swap` on the parameter instance.

```
void setFoo(FooSP newFoo) { std::swap(mFoo, newFoo); }
```

If I were required to implement something along the lines of what you are proposing, I would create a static instance of `Foo` to serve as the null version, and then have the `increment` method throw an exception if it was the null version.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  static Foo Null;
  //...
  void  increment() {
      if (this == &Null) throw Null;
      mFoo++;
  }
  //...
};

struct DeleteFoo {
    void operator () (Foo *t) const {
        if (t != &Foo::Null) delete t;
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass() : mFoo(&Foo::Null, DeleteFoo()) {}
  //...
};
```

Note the custom deleter for `FooSP` to properly deal with `Foo::Null`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I'm going with @justin's answer because it was slightly more explicit, but you've definitely been a big help.

Comment: @Michael: No worries! Please also read the edit I just added for how to do what you originally proposed in a better way.

Comment: +1, but I'd take out the part about const&. A better way to optimize away refcount fiddling is to leave the implicit copy, but replace the explicit assignment with a swap. (See Dave Abrahams' article at http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/.) But neither one is guaranteed to help anything, and it probably won't matter anyway.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the feedback. I incorporated your suggestion, so please leave your comment up so people know where credit is due. Regards.